# ¿Cómo ajustar adecuadamente un árbol de decisión para poder graficarlo en R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, tree

Estoy intentando **graficar el objeto resultante de ajustar un modelo de árbol de decisión**, pero me encuentro con varios problemas:

```
tree_model<- tree(High~ ShelveLoc + Price + Advertising + Income + Age + CompPrice,
                 data = data,na.action = "na.exclude", control = tree.control(nobs = 400, minsize = 1))
```

Tras ejecutar lo anterior me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

```
Warning messages:
1: In tree(High ~ ShelveLoc + Price + Advertising + Income + Age +  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In tree(High ~ ShelveLoc + Price + Advertising + Income + Age +  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Por lo que entiendo del mensaje, creo que algunos valores faltantes puedes estar afectando negativamente al ajuste del modelo, así que he probado con varias opciones en el argumento `na.action`, pero siempre aparece el mismo mensaje. Por otro lado he revisado el dataframe y no hay ningún valor faltante, además he modificado los parámetros de `tree.control` y sigo sin obtener el gráfico.

Seguidamente intento graficar el modelo:

```
plot(tree_model)
```

Pero aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
Error in plot.tree(tree_model) : cannot plot singlenode tree
```

Que por lo que he leído suele ser debido a que mis datos tienen muy poca varianza y esto hace que solo exista un único nodo en mi árbol, pero al ser un ejercicio de clase sé que debería generarse un árbol con varios nodos y probablemente se me esté escapando algo en la función `tree()`. Tras revisar el PDF disponible en el CRAN del paquete en cuestión sigo sin saber qué argumento incluir o modificar en la función.

**¿Qué debo modificar en mi código para obtener el gráfico que deseo?**

Comment: El error esta diciendo que tú árbol tiene un solo nodo por eso no es posible graficarlo.

Comment: Sí, justo eso comento en mi pregunta, que solo hay un nodo pero debo modificar algo en el código para que se genere un árbol con varios nodos. Es un ejercicio de clase y por eso sé que debo modificar algo para que se generen varios nodos

Comment: ¿ Hay muchos valores faltantes ? Es posible que de sre así la exclusión de los mismos te deja con un set de entrenamiento que no tiene ninguna ganancia de información al momento de entrenar, por eso solo queda un único nodo del árbol.

Comment: Pues he revisado la existencia de valores faltantes en mi dataframe, pero creo que puedo asegurar que no los hay, así que no entiendo el mensaje de aviso al ejecutar el ```tree()```.

Comment: Intenta aumentar la cantidad de datos del set de train con un valor de nobs mayor y el minsplit dejarlo en el default que es 10

Comment: Verifica por favor que `High` sea un `factor` o al menos que sea una variable numérica,  si no lo es conviertela y vuelve a probar. En la ayuda de la función te da una pista: `The left-hand-side (response) should be either a numerical vector when a regression tree will be fitted or a factor,`

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era ese, que no declaré high como una variable factor. Sinceramente fue un despiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estamos ante un problema de clasificación has probado a convertir  tu variable objetivo (high) a 'factor'. En caso de que no sea clasificación o no sea ese el problema comenta y tratamos de buscar una respuesta entre todos.

P. D. : Si me permites un consejo para la próxima ocasión siempre se agradece un poco de contexto, ¿estas ante un problema de regresión o clasificación? , ¿que paquete estas usando y que versión? esto puede facilitar que te ayuden en el futuro, según se compliquen los problemas a los que te enfrentes.

Comment: Las aclaraciones se deben realizar como comentario, no en respuestas, saludos.

Comment: En mi opinión la conversión a factor si es una respuesta a la pregunta. De hecho entiendo que la correcta porque normalmente el error que comenta se debe a ello. En cuanto a lo de dejar la sugerencia en comentarios tienen razón.